# What was "The Atreides Manifesto" and why was it important?

Tags: dune, heretics-of-dune

In *Heretics of Dune*, Odrade writes "The Atreides Manifesto" under Taraza's direction and guidance. What was this manifesto? Why is it so important? Herbert never clearly describes it or its purpose. Or, does he? It just sort of fizzles out.

If this document is just another piece of the Sisterhood's arsenal, seemingly intended to create discord among the more powerful factions, why does Taraza exploit Odrade? Odrade wondered that the manifesto made her vulnerable and blamed Taraza.

What was Taraza's purpose or plan? Why make a potential RM vulnerable?

Comment: Discussed at some length here; https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/alt.fan.dune/lVezU1lNfWo

Comment: That was very useful. What it didn't answer was this: What was the importance of an Atreides being the author?

Answer (score 10):

The manifesto itself isn't spelled out in any great detail. It's discussed by a number of the characters (see below) and we can kinda see the edges of it but at its heart, the power of the document appears come from its **celebrity value**; that it was written by a descendant of the Tyrant, arguably the most powerful single individual in the galaxy's history.

Its effects seem to be transformative, well beyond the words themselves. Odrade has used her talents as an Atreides to create the literary equivalent of an [earworm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earworm).

---

> Mirlat will have to be dealt with, Waff thought. He lifted the
>   manifesto from his lap and read the first line aloud: “*In the
>   beginning was the word and the word was God*.”

Waff describes it as calling religions (save their own) into question, presumably because theirs is the only major religion to herald Leto II as a messenger of the true God:

> “Every powindah religion is called into question by this manifesto,”
>   Waff said. “**Every faith except ours is left hanging in limbo**.”

Teg has read it. It's pretty densely worded:

> “*Just as the universe is created by the participation of
>   consciousness, the prescient human carries that creative faculty to
>   its ultimate extreme. This was the profoundly misunderstood power of
>   the Atreides bastard, the power that he transmitted to his son, the
>   Tyrant.*”

It evidently discusses the power of prophecy:

> **In a deep and portentous tone, Odrade said: “The Manifesto raises
>   questions that all must address, believers and non-believers alike.”**
>
> “What has all this to do with the Holy Child?” Tuek demanded. “You
>   told me we must meet on matters concerning—”
>
> Before Tuek could find words, Waff locked eyes with Odrade and
>   responded in a way he knew she would interpret correctly. Odrade could
>   do no less, being who she was.
>
> “**The error of prescience,**” Waff said. “Isn’t that what this document
>   calls it? Isn’t that where it says the mind of the believer
>   stagnates?”

It's decidedly heretical:

> She had to keep Tuek’s attention on the document that disturbed him so
>   much. She paraphrased from the Manifesto: “Your will and your
>   faith—your belief system—dominate your universe.”
>
> Tuek recognized the words. He had read the terrible document. **This
>   Manifesto said God and all of His works were no more than human
>   creations.** He wondered how he should respond. No High Priest could let
>   such a thing go unchallenged.

Comment: I like the "earworm" metaphore.  I think Odrade was using her "Gift" (recognizing threats to the BG) to write a document intended to uncover real threats

Comment: Had not considered elevating Odrade's status to such a height, but it does fit the context and the implications of the manifesto. I'd considered Teg the most powerful Atreides scion, until now. Will we ever know what Herbert intended with Odrade, was his mission to create a character to be discussed more intensely at some point? Is that point now?